# Swift restrict generic type to Type

Tags: ios, swift, generics, protocols

How can I restrict a generic type to be a type, not an instance of a type?

If I have a class:

`class SomeClass<T: SomeProtocol> {}`

how can I ensure that `T` is only an instance of `AnyClass` (which is just `AnyObject.Type`)

My protocol only has static methods and in order to call those methods I have to do `instance.dynamicType.protocolMethod` whereas I want to do `someType.protocolMethod`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, Swift does not allow you to use a metatype as a generic type. (I believe this is along the lines of what Sam Giddins [wished for in Swift 3](https://realm.io/news/swift-3-wishlist/).)

You can, however, use it as a value. Instead of making `T` a type parameter, make it a property:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    static func foo()
}

struct Concrete: SomeProtocol {
    static func foo() {
        print("I am concrete")
    }
}

class SomeClass {
    let T: SomeProtocol.Type

    init(T: SomeProtocol.Type) {
        self.T = T
    }

    func go() {
        T.foo()  // no need for dynamicType
    }
}

SomeClass(T: Concrete.self).go()
```

If, as you say, your protocol contains only static methods, then this is sufficient. However, if you need to tie a generic parameter to the type, that’s possible too:

```
class SomeClass<U: SomeProtocol> {
    let T: U.Type

    init(T: U.Type) {
        self.T = T
    }

    func go(value: U) {
        T.foo()
    }
}

SomeClass(T: Concrete.self).go(Concrete())
```

Comment: That's too bad that you can't use metatypes for a generic. Either way I believe your solutions works the best.

Answer (score 0):

```
protocol P {
    static func foo()
}
class A : P {
    static func foo() {
        print("A class")
    }
}
class B : P {
    static func foo() {
        print("C class")
    }
}

var type1 = A.self
var type2 = B.self

func check(cls: AnyClass)->Void {
    switch cls {
    case is A.Type:
        A.foo()
    case is B.Type:
        B.foo()
    default:
        break
    }
}

check(type1) // A class
check(type2) // C class

let i = Int.self         // Int.Type
let ao = AnyObject.self  // AnyObject.Protocol
let ac = AnyClass.self   // AnyClass.Protocol
let p = P.self           // P.Protocol
let f = check.self       // (AnyClass)->Void
```

Edit

```
protocol P {
    static func f()
}
class A : P {
    static func f() {
        print("A")
    }
}
class B : P {
    static func f() {
        print("B")
    }
}

func f(cls: P.Type) {
    cls.f()
}

f(A)  // A
f(B)  // B

class Test<T: P> {
    func foo() {
        T.f()
    }
}

Test<A>().foo() // A
Test<B>().foo() // B
```

Comment: Again, this doesn't deal with generics.

Comment: Again, AnyClass is the protocol to which ALL class types IMPLICITLY conform. May be I just don't understand your question.

Comment: AnyClass isn't a protocol, it's a typealias for `AnyObject.Type`. `AnyObject` however is a protocol.

Comment: please, check the documentation. (cmd-click in playground should work)

Comment: I did. Did you @user3441734?
`@objc public protocol AnyObject {}`

`public typealias AnyClass = AnyObject.Type`

Comment: Yes, I did. 
'let anyclass = AnyClass.self // AnyClass.Protocol
let anyobject = AnyObject.self // AnyObject.Protocol